# How can I get a notification in my Android application when there is any insertion in DynamoDB?

Tags: android, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb

My android application will update the DynamoDB and some specific user group should get the notification on this update (similar to WhatsApp broadcast where the group will be fixed).

I have searched about it and I found that DynamoDB streams can be used to achieve this. Please guide me how I can do it.

Answer (score 0):

You can put condition for database modification and if any found then you can push notification by android notification service.